# How to ssh into dockovpn server via vpn ip

Tags: ssh, docker, openvpn

I've deployed a [DockOvpn](https://github.com/dockovpn/dockovpn) and I want to connect to host running ovpn docker container via ssh. The connection itself seems ok. I tried to connect via the VPN ip (both inet addr and p-2-p addr) that is shown in ifconfig for the tun0 interface within ovpn container, but connection could not be established. The goal is to ssh jump via the dockovpn into computers in local network.

Generated OVPN file:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
cipher AES-256-GCM
auth SHA512
verb 3
tls-client
tls-version-min 1.2
key-direction 1
remote-cert-tls server
remote // EXTERNAL_IP // 1194
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
// CERTIFICAT BODY //
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
<cert>
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            // CERTIFICATE_SERIAL_NUMER //
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: CN=Easy-RSA CA
        Validity
            Not Before: Jul 30 20:57:44 2023 GMT
            Not After : Nov  1 20:57:44 2025 GMT
        Subject: CN=// HASH //
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                RSA Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    // MODULUS_BODY //
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                // BASE 16 HASH //
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                // BASE 16 HASH //
                DirName:/CN=Easy-RSA CA
                // BASE 16 HASH //

            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Client Authentication
            X509v3 Key Usage: 
                Digital Signature
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
                // BASE 16 HASH //
         fd:4e:64:c9
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
                // CERT BIDY //
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>
<key>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
                // KEY BODY //
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>
<tls-auth>
#
# 2048 bit OpenVPN static key
#
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
                // KEY BODY //
-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----
</tls-auth>
;client-id // CLIENT ID //
```

### References

- [Original question on github](https://github.com/dockovpn/dockovpn/issues/201)